# Distinguish between empty string and null in JSON

Tags: jquery, json, null, string

I'm using jQuery to deserialize a JSON response from a server, but I need to distinguish between *empty* and *null* values:

Sample response:

```
{
    "Key1": "Value1",
    "Key2": null,
    "Key3": ""
}
```

I can see that in the raw JSON string the two values are distinct, but when I deserialize both `Key2` and `Key3` are `null`. Is there anyway I can convince the jQuery deserializer not to treat these values as identical?

Comment: What browser? Chrome properly handles `null` vs `""`. I suspect this will be a browser JSON.parse implementation problem and not a jQuery problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with jQuery's `$.parseJSON`. How is the JSON being deserialized?

Comment: Unsetting `JSON.parse` (forcing use of jQuery's polyfill) still properly decodes the two keys distinctly to `null` and `""`. Can you `console.log($.parseJSON(json_string))` and post its contents in your question? Could it be that the keys are correctly decoded, but other code fails to distinguish between `null` and empty string?

Comment: D'oh! Found the problem: someone else on the stack was checking `if (value)` where it should have been `if (value == null)`, and it happened early enough that even my log messages were seeing the wrongly-normalized code.